# Не могу исправить код для задания на stepik.org

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, list, список

Задание звучит так:"Напишите функцию modify_list(l), которая принимает на вход список целых чисел, удаляет из него все нечётные значения, а чётные нацело делит на два. Функция не должна ничего возвращать, требуется только изменение переданного списка, например:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(modify_list(lst))  # None
print(lst)               # [1, 2, 3]
modify_list(lst)
print(lst)               # [1]

lst = [10, 5, 8, 3]
modify_list(lst)
print(lst)               # [5, 4]
```

Функция не должна осуществлять ввод/вывод информации."

Мой код выглядит вот так (возможно он очень кривой, но я еще учусь :)) :

```
def modify_list(l):
    for i in l:
        if i%2==1:
            l.remove(i)
    L=[]
    for i in l:
        if len(l)!=0:
            i=i//2
            L+=[i]
    l.clear()
    l.extend(L)
    return(l)
```

Код отлично работает когда в списке содержаться значения из примера (lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] и lst = [10, 5, 8, 3]), но когда в списке содержатся только нечётные значения, то программа, как и требуется, убирает все нечётные числа, но почему-то оставляет одно-два числа. Например, когда в списке находятся числа [1, 13, 7, 3], то программа на этапе проверка чётности или нечётности числа оставляет [13], и,  соответственно в выводе даёт число [6].

Товарищи, не могли бы вы мне, глупенькому начинающему программисту, подсказать, как решить данный конфуз?

Answer (score 2):

я это так решил:

```
def modify_list(l):
    i, n = 0, len(l)
    while i < n:
        if l[i] % 2:
            l.pop(i)
            n -= 1
        else:
            l[i] = l[i] // 2
            i += 1
```

зато читаемо и красиво

Answer (score 1):

Этот вопрос тут задают чуть не каждый день. Нельзя удалять элементы из списка, по которому вы итерируетесь - перебор элементов при этом ломается. Самое простое решение тут - итерироваться в `for` по копии списка, полученной через `l[:]`, любо через `l.copy()`, либо через `list(l)`.

Но вообще pythonic way - это не модифицировать имеющийся список, а создавать новый с помощью фильтрации, спискового включения и т.д. Тогда точно никаких проблем не будет. Ну если только ваш список не гигантский, а удалений/изменений мало - тогда допустимо модифицировать имеющийся список "на месте" (inplace).

Answer (score 0):

добавлю сюда, потому что тоже не поняла до конца условия, т.к. формулировки не очень, и сама полезла искать ответы, не найдя ничего толкового

```
def modify_list(lst):

    global l
    l = [i // 2 for i in lst if i % 2 == 0]
```

объявляем новую глобальную переменную, это будет обновленный список
через list comprehension, пробегаясь по всем элементам в исходном списке, выбираем из них только четные, сразу добавляем это число поделенное на два в новый список

Comment: В формировании списка подход правильный, но почему вы уверены, что внешняя переменная со списком будет обязательно называться `l`? Вам нужно модифицировать тот список, который передали в функцию, как он называется снаружи функции вы не можете знать наверняка. Поэтому подход с `global` в корне не верный.